# React-native: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have seen similar questions asked but I can't seem to indentify the problem.
I am using react native v 0.27
I have changed all my require methods into imports.

Here's the error I receive:

[image]

I don't know if its relevant, but the first position of the error points to my LoginComp.js file which contains the following code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class LoginComp extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={this.props.styles.loginLogoContainer}>
          <Image style={this.props.styles.view1logo} source={require('../imgs/Logo.png')} />
        </View>
        <View style={this.props.styles.loginContainer}>
          <Text>Użytkownik:</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={this.props.styles.defaultInput}
            placeholder="Użytkownik"
            stretch={true}
            autoComplete={false}
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
          <Text>Hasło:</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={this.props.styles.defaultInput}
            placeholder="Hasło"
            stretch={true}
            autoComplete={false}
            autoCorrect={false}
            secureTextEntry={true}
          />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.LoginPress}>
            <Text style={this.props.styles.loginButton}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={this.props.styles.registrationWrapper}>
          <Text>- lub -</Text>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.t_Registration}>
            <Text style={this.props.styles.registration}>Załóż nowe konto</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = LoginComp;
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Change your import statement like below and try.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
```

Also constructor should be like below

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
```

Comment: thank you - it solved my problem. But why does it have to be that way ?

Comment: In the latest version of react native, 'React' and 'Component' is moved from 'react-native' to 'react' module. So you will have to import it using the above way.

Comment: and whats about context pass to the constructor??

Comment: Two tips: 1) If your only statement in the constructor is to call `super`, you can leave out the constructor completely. ES6 will implicitly call `super` when the constructor is omitted. 2) If you do want your constructor present, I recommend you call super like so: `constructor() { super(...arguments) }`. That will ensure all your arguments get passed along.

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same issue. Wrongly imported

```
import React, { Component } from "react-native";
```

instead of

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676646/5367816

Answer (score 5):

I hit this error when attempting to use:

```
class Leaderboard extends React.component {

}
```

It should have been Component with a capital C!

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I solved this problem in another way:

I was importing a default module like `import Module from "./path/to/Module.js"`.
But in the `Module.js` file, **I ommited the default keyword**:
`export class Module {/*...*/}` **->** `export default class Module {/*...*/}`

Hope this will help someone. =)

Answer (score 0):

just add the props in App.js file

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component

Answer (score 0):

May be latest version of expo/react native does not support @expo/react-native-action-sheet@2.5.0

upgrading @expo/react-native-action-sheet works for me:

yarn add  @expo/react-native-action-sheet@latest